# Jenkin's Git Build Trigger: build every intermediate revision, not just HEAD?

Tags: git, triggers, continuous-integration, jenkins, gerrit

Using Jenkins, git and the Jenkins Git Plugin: If I push multiple revisions at once, only the last revision will be built. **How do I get Jenkins to build all revisions in between ?**

Or is there a "Choosing Strategy" other than "Default" that I select ?

I know this is possible in combination with Gerrit (see http://vimeo.com/20084957 ) for a very impressive demo) and that's where I want to go eventually — but I don't want to introduce Gerrit just for this feature.

Comment: Your link to vimeo is wrong (the 8 should be a ")").

Answer (score 3):

I built a git tool to do this called [git test-sequence](http://dustin.github.com/2010/03/28/git-test-sequence.html).

If you know the previous change ID and the new change ID, you can tell it to test what's between them.

Comment: Right, both your and Andrew Bayer's blog post ( http://about.digg.com/blog/continuous-deployment-code-review-and-pre-tested-commits-digg4 ) were jaw-dropping when I read them. This is why  I added this to my secret wishlist.

Comment: The link is dead, archive at http://web.archive.org/web/20120309031920/http://about.digg.com/blog/continuous-deployment-code-review-and-pre-tested-commits-digg4